# PowerShell script to convert one-column CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm looking for a script, doesn't have to be in PS but must run under Windows, that converts a one column text file like below

```
abc
def
ghi
```

into

```
'abc',
'def',
'ghi'
```

I'm currently making this change in Excel using =concatenate, but a script would be better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use can use a regular expression to insert characters at beginning and end.

```
get-content ./myonlinecolumn.txt | foreach {$_ -replace "^","'" -replace "`$","',"}
```

Or you could use the format operator -f:

```
get-content ./myonlinecolumn.txt  | foreach {"'{0}'," -f $_ }
```

Its a bit more work to remove the last trailing comma, but this also possible

```
$a = get-content ./myonlinecolumn.txt
get-content ./myonlinecolumn.txt | foreach { if ($_.readcount -lt $a.count) {"'{0}'," -f $_ } else {"'{0}'" -f $_ }}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there an easy way to trim the values (remove leading/trailing whitespace)? If not, I can make do.

Answer (score 3):

My first idea was similar to what Chad already wrote, that is a check on the line number. So I've tried a different solution. Not very nice but I post it too :)

```
((gc c:\before.txt | % {"'"+$_+"'"} ) -join ",*").split("*") | out-file c:\after.txt
```

Comment: You can join with ",{backtick}n" and then leave out the `.split` :) (used {backtick} because of bad formatting here on SO)

Comment: Can you briefly explain how it works? I understand Chad's script, but not this one.

Comment: @Sean, the idea is: `(gc c:\before.txt | % {"'"+$_+"'"} ) -join ",{backtick}n" | out-file c:\after.txt`. The parenthesis there are needed to evaluate the first pipeline (it returns array of strings). Then it is joined with `,``n` (where *{backtick}n* is *new line*, same as `\n` in other languages. And the result is piped to `out-file`. test ``n` test

Comment: Hi stej. Thanks for the advice. I didn't think about it. :)

Comment: This also breaks if one of the strings contains a `*`.

Comment: @Joey. Obviously my script, without stej improvement, supposed that you use some char that you're sure is not present within text file.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
(gc myfile | %{"'$_'"}) -join ',
'
```

or, if you love escapes:

```
(gc myfile | %{"'$_'"}) -join ",`n"
```

This loads the file into an array of strings (`Get-Content`), then processes each string by putting it into single quotes. (Use `"'$($_.Trim())'" if you need to trim whitespace, too). Then the lines are joined with a comma and line break (those can be embedded directly into strings).

If your values can contain single quotes (which need to be escaped) it's trivial to stick that in there, too:

```
(gc myfile | %{"'$($_.Trim() -replace "'","''")'"}) -join ",`n"
```